# Packages PKG Mac Installation builder Presentation Tab Doesn't Load

Tags: macos, installation, package

I am using the Packages software to build my application into a pkg file for installation on other Macs.  I've used it before on my old MacBook and it worked great. I am trying it on my new Mac and I cannot view the Presentation Tab.  Whenever I click the Presentation Tab under Project, the screen stays the same as the prior tab I was on. So I can't configure the Presentation.  Has anyone else had this problem? I've reinstalled Packages and still no change. I'm not sure if my configurations are wrong or what's going on. I'm running Ventura 13.0.1 on my MacBook.

I'm including a screenshot that shows the Presentation Tab is active, but the Settings tab is still visible (that's the tab I switched from).

I'd love some help, I really want to configure the presentation.  Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and got in touch with the Packages dev team. They provided this link to dev build, which fixes this issue now. I suppose in the next release it is going to be fixed.

http://s.sudre.free.fr/files/Packages_1211_dev.dmg

Comment: Somehow it does not always work when you click the link, but if you copy it and paste in the address bar, it downloads the dmg.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I should have contacted them too. :)

Comment: Still I can't download the package of version 1.2.11

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT open the url in browser,you should use this command:

```
wget http://s.sudre.free.fr/files/Packages_1211_dev.dmg
hdiutil attach Packages_1211_dev.dmg
cp /Volumes/Packages\ 1.2.11/packages/Packages.pkg ./
```

then double click the Packages.pkg file,you will install success and solve the problem!